# Object type property not recognized inside LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have this code:

```
var siteObject = getObjectModels(context, contractsIDList, date);
var clientObjSitesList = bridgeTable_clientObjModel(models, contracts, clients, siteObject);

private static IQueryable<object> bridgeTable_clientObjModel(
    IQueryable<ObjectModel> objModels,                                                     
    IQueryable<Contract> contracts,
    IQueryable<Client> client,
    IQueryable<SiteObject> siteObject)
{
    var clientObjSitesList = 
        from cn in contracts
        join cl in client on cn.Id equals cl.Id
        join so in siteObject on cn.Id equals so.ContractId
        select new
        {
            clientId = cl.Id,
            modelId = so.ModelId,
        });
}

private static object createClientTypesObjectList(
    IQueryable<Object> clientObjSitesList, 
    IQueryable<ObjectModel> models, 
    IQueryable<Contract> contracts, 
    IQueryable<Client> clients, 
    IQueryable<SiteObject> siteObject)
{
    var clientTypesObjectList = 
        (from cob in clientObjSitesList
         join om in models on cob.modelId equals om.Id into g
         from subpet in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new
         {
             clientId = cob.clientId,
             modelId = cob.modelId,
             typeId = (subpet == null ? -1 : subpet.ObjectTypeId)

         }).ToList();
}
```

In this function **createClientTypesObjectList()** in this row:

```
 join om in models on cob.modelId equals om.Id into g
```

I get this error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'modelId' and no extension method 'modelId' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

As I understand the problem occure because I return object type in this function: `bridgeTable_clientObjModel()`

Any idea how can I fix the problem?How can I make modelId property recognized in **createClientTypesObjectList()** function?

Comment: you could use dynamic or switch to a strongly typed representation.

Comment: "As I understand the problem occure because I return anonymus type in this function: `bridgeTable_clientObjModel()`" -- No. `IQueryable<object> bridgeTable_clientObjModel(...)` means you're returning `IQueryable<object>`. There's no anonymous type in there, it's just that `object` doesn't have the properties you want to access. (Knowing that doesn't directly help for solving your problem, though.)

Answer (score 0):

The element in 'clientObjSitesList' are of type object which doesn't have the modeId property. You can:

1. Change the type of the parameter to 
   `IQueryable<YourType>clientObjSitesList`
2. Cast the object in your query:

   `join om in models on ((YourType)cob).modelId equals om.Id into g`
3. Use Dynamic as your type.

Comment: Maor,can I access the property using reflection?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the `clientObjSitesLists` parameter, you define the type as `IQueryable<Object>`. When you iterate over it you have an `Object`, which has no properties.

```
private static object createClientTypesObjectList(
    IQueryable<Object> clientObjSitesList, // <- this line
    IQueryable<ObjectModel> models,
```

You probably mean to declare this as `IQueryable<SiteObject>`, or some other type.

Comment: I dont have objectmodel  type.Do you have any idea can I use reflection?

Comment: There must be a type or interface for this object. Where does it come from?